# Named Entity Recognition using NLTK. Relevance of extracted keywords

Tags: nltk, relevance, named-entity-recognition

I was checking out the Named Entity Recognition feature of NLTK. Is it possible to find out which of the extracted keywords is most relevant to the original text? Also, is it possible to know the type (Person / Organization) of the extracted keywords?

Answer (score 7):

If you have a trained tagger, you can first tag your text and then use the NE classifier that comes with NLTK.

The tagged text should be presented as a list

```
sentence = 'The U.N.'
tagged_sentence = [('The','DT'), ('U.N.', 'NNP')]
```

Then, the ne classifier would be called like this

```
nltk.ne_chunk(tagged_sentence)
```

It returns a Tree. The classified words will appear as Tree nodes inside the main structure. 
The result will include if it is a PERSON, ORGANIZATION or GPE.

To find out the most relevant terms, you have to define a measure of "relevance". Usually [tf/idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) is used but if you are considering only one document, frequency could be enough.

Computing the frequency of each word within a document is easy with NLTK. First you have to load your corpus and once you have load it and have a Text object, simply call:

```
relevant_terms_sorted_by_freq = nltk.probability.FreqDist(corpus).keys()
```

Finally, you could filter out all words in relevant_terms_sorted_by_freq that don't belong to a NE list of words.

[NLTK offers an online version of a complete book](http://www.nltk.org/book) which I find interesting to start with